# Как ответить на SendMessage

Tags: c, winapi, sendmessage

Есть два процесса: Сервер для ввода команд (In) и Сервер для обработки команд (Out)

И вот я отправляю SendMessage() из In в Out

А Out выполнив действия, должен ответить на сообщение...

Кто знает - как это сделать (как ответить?)

Comment: Возвратить результат обработки сообщения. `case YourMsg: { Обработка; Return = нужный результат }`.

Comment: @Dima, и как это сделать? Еще учитывайте, что хэндл In неизвестен

Comment: SendMessage не подразумевает ответа. Если нужно назад что то то ответить, то либо в sendmessage нужно предоставить достаточно информации (хендл к примеру) или использовать PostMessage, который как раз может возвратить результат.

Comment: @KoVadim, как это не подразумевает ответа? [Выдержка из docs.microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage): `The return value specifies the result of the message processing; it depends on the message sent`.

Comment: Как же Вы тогда собрались отправлять сообщение? Используете `HWND_BROADCAST`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не `SendMessage` отправляете, а вызываете `SendMessage` для отправки сообщения. Приемник получает это сообщение через вызов `GetMessage` и вызывает соответствующий обработчик, который это сообщение обрабатывает и выполняет оператор `return` с кодом завершения, который и передается как результат выполнения `SendMessage`.

Если источник и приемник находятся в разных процессах, то сообщение должно быть зарегистрировано и там и там. Например, послать сообщение можно так:

```
#define GOOD_RESULT   0
#define BAD_RESULT    1

static const TCHAR szMyMessage[] = _TEXT("My global message");
static UINT wmMyMessage = 0;
. . .
// Послать сообщение
if (wmMyMessage == 0) wmMyMessage = ::RegisterWindowsMessage(szMyMessage);
LRESULT res = ::SendMessage(hWnd, wmMyMessage, (WPARAM)arg1, (LPARAM)arg2);
// Проверить ответ
if (res == BAD_RESULT) PrintErrorMessageAndQuit();
_ASSERTE (res == GOOD_RESULT);
// Успешно, продолжить работу
```

А принять и ответить можно так:

```
#define GOOD_RESULT   0
#define BAD_RESULT    1

static const TCHAR szMyMessage[] = _TEXT("My global message");
static UINT wmMyMessage = 0;

static LRESULT OnMyMessage(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  bool bSuccess;
  // Сделать что-нибудь полезное
  . . .
  return bSuccess ? GOOD_RESULT : BAD_RESULT;
}

static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
  switch (uMsg) {
    . . . // Вызовы других обработчиков

    default:
      if (uMsg == wmMyMessage)
        return OnMyMessage(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
      else
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
  }
}

int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) {
  wmMyMessage = ::RegisterWindowsMessage(szMyMessage);
  . . .
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: А можно как-то вернуть строку?

Comment: @Alrott SlimRG, непосредственно вернуть можно только LRESULT. Для более сложных данных уже нужно устанавливать какой-то канал коммуникации. Вариантов тут много - простейший пример: обработчик записывает данные во временный файл с числовым именем nnnn.tmp, и возвращает число nnnn как результат 'SendMessage'. А вызывающая программа соответственно этот файл читает и удаляет. Можно использовать именованные [каналы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/ipc/pipes), можно использовать DDE, mailslots, memory-mapped файлы, можно посылать строки через WM_COPYDATA. Вариантов много.

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!!!